# Python Division Accuracy Issue, possibly

Tags: python, division

When I calculate below division in python, the result returns as 1. How do I get the actual float number?

```
1/(1+3.0573630308660312e-30)
Out[182]: 1.0
```

Comment: You can't, not with `float`. `(1+3.0573630308660312e-30)` is 1.0, because floating point numbers can't represent that small a fraction over 1. The limit is `sys.float_info.epsilon`, roughly 16 decimal digits small.

Comment: If you need to work with offsets from 1 *this small*, use the `decimal.Decimal` type.